# Is there any practical difference between the .net decimal values 1m and 1.0000m?

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

Is there any practical difference between the .net decimal values 1m and 1.0000m?

The internal storage is different:

```
1m      : 0x00000001 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
1.0000m : 0x000186a0 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00050000
```

But, is there a situation where the knowledge of "significant digits" would be used by a method in the BCL?

I ask because I'm working on a means of compressing the space required for decimal values for disk storage or network transport and am toying with the idea of "normalizing" the value before I store it to improve it's compressability. But, I'd like to know if it is likely to cause issues down the line. I'm guessing that it should be fine, but only because I don't see any methods or properties that expose the precision of the value. Does anyone know otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is so invoking `ToString returns the exact textual representation in the source code.

```
Console.WriteLine(1m); // 1
Console.WriteLine(1.000m); // 1.000
```

Comment: -1: How could "ToString" know anything about the source code?

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to give some thought about whether I care or not.

Comment: @Chaos: nonsense. Find a better explanation, but not that one. Do you know any other feature of .NET where information about the source is stored? Not metadata, but actual information about the source code.

Comment: @John - I thought it was obvious that the precision is in fact the meta data retrieved from the source code.

Comment: @Chaos: "the source code" would be the textual representation. What happens if you add a leading zero?

Comment: @John, @Chaos, the reason for this is that the Decimal data type is actually stored as an integer with a divisor (scale). So when the number 1.000m is encoded into the Decimal data type it is stored as 1000 and a scale of 3 and the number 1 is stored as a 1 with a scale of 0.

Comment: -1 That's not the answer. If you write `decimal d = 1.000;` and then `d *= 784;`, `ToString()` will return `784.000`. Obviously, it's using something internal rather than the "exact textual representation."

Comment: I think everyone is tripping up over semantic details here, what it appears that @ChaosPandion means is that it stores the representation of the number as it was entered into the source code, which is true.

Comment: 7 upvotes! Some mental models of how computers work need to be recalibrated

Comment: While his "mental model" may be flawed, it was the only answer provided that actually gave an example that satisfied my question.

Answer (score 13):

The reason for the difference in encoding is because the Decimal data type stores the number as a whole number (96 bit integer), with a scale which is used to form the divisor to get the fractional number. The value is essentially

```
integer / 10^scale
```

Internally the Decimal type is represented as 4 Int32, see the documentation of [Decimal.GetBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx) for more detail. In summary, GetBits returns an array of 4 Int32s, where each element represents the follow portion of the Decimal encoding

```
Element 0,1,2 - Represent the low, middle and high 32 bits on the 96 bit integer
Element 3     - Bits 0-15 Unused
                Bits 16-23 exponent which is the power of 10 to divide the integer by
                Bits 24-30 Unused 
                Bit 31 the sign where 0 is positive and 1 is negative
```

So in your example, very simply put when 1.0000m is encoded as a decimal the actual representation is `10000 / 10^4` while 1m is represented as `1 / 10^0` mathematically the same value just encoded differently.

If you use the native .NET operators for the decimal type and do not manipulate/compare the bit/bytes yourself you should be safe.

You will also notice that the string conversions will also take this binary representation into consideration and produce different strings so you need to be careful in that case if you ever rely on the string representation.

Comment: Small nitpick:  It's not Byte 1,2,3 but rather (4 byte quartet).  Or maybe you could just say that the first 12 bytes hold the integer value.

Comment: @Matt Brunell, you are absolutely correct! Thank you for that I corrected answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

The `decimal` type tracks scale because it's important in arithmetic. If you do long multiplication, by hand, of two numbers — for instance, 3.14 * 5.00 — the result has 6 digits of *precision* and a *scale* of 4.

To do the multiplication, ignore the decimal points (for now) and treat the two numbers as integers.

```
  3.14
* 5.00
------
  0000 -- 0 * 314 (0 in the one's place)
 00000 -- 0 * 314 (0 in the 10's place)
157000 -- 5 * 314 (5 in the 100's place)
------
157000
```

That gives you the unscaled results. Now, count the total number of digits to the right of the decimal point in the expression (that would be 4) and insert the decimal point 4 places to the left:

```
15.7000
```

That result, while equivalent in value to 15.7, is more **precise** than the value 15.7. The value 15.7000 has 6 digits of precision and a scale of 4; 15.7 has 3 digits of precision and a scale of 1.

If one is trying to do precision arithmetic, it is important to track the precision and scale of your values and results as it tells you something about the precision of your results (note that precision isnt' the same as accuracy: measure something with a ruler graduated in 1/10ths of an inch and the best you can say about the resulting measurement, no matter how many trailing zeros you put to the right of the decimal point is that it is accurate to, at best, a 1/10th of an inch. Another way of putting it would be to say that your measurement is accurate, at best, within +/- 5/100ths of the stated value.

Comment: Unfortunately, the way in which `Decimal` tracks precision does not reliably maintain any information about the precision of the numbers involved.  Division by numbers which are not of the form 2^n * 5^n will yield the maximum representable number of digits, regardless of whether those digits represent any real accuracy, and nothing indicates when subtraction results in catastrophic cancellation.