# Why is decimal value 0 different from 0.0

Tags: c#

This is just a question to advance my own knowledge because I found something not behaving as expected. Consider the following code

```
decimal d0 = 0;
decimal d1 = 0M;
decimal d2 = 0.0M;

string s0 = d0.ToString();
string s1 = d1.ToString();
string s2 = d2.ToString();
```

The debugger will show `d0` and `d1` as `0` in a watch window. But it will show `d2` as `0.0`. The strings `s0` and `s1` will contain `"0"`. But `s2` will contain `"0.0"`.

Why is this? Of course `0 == 0.00`. In fact `(d1 == d2)` returns `true`. So why does C# treat these differently internally?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you see in debugger, what matter is [internal decimal representation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15348989/1997232), which makes `0` and `0.0` seems different. [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5759355/1997232).

Comment: _"The scaling factor also preserves any trailing zeros in a Decimal number. Trailing zeros do not affect the value of a Decimal number in arithmetic or comparison operations. However, **trailing zeros might be revealed by the ToString method if an appropriate format string is applied**."_ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Try calling `decimal.GetBits(d0)` and compare the results with `decimal.GetBits(d1)`.

Comment: @DavidG You are right. `GetBits()` returns differently. `[0,0,0,0]` vs `[0,0,0,65536]`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Brilliant, thank you!

Comment: When I say `d0 = 0`, I am expressing an *infinite* amount of significant digits. The answer is **0**. That's it. Yet it internally seems to think I was unsure and that my significant digits are unknown. Guess I'm not a fan of this behavior.